# How can I directly connect to the internet using a WRT-54GL

Tags: wifi, router, firmware

I have a WRT-54GL, a Thomson DSL modem/router and a DSL line (PPPoE). I currently connect the Thomson to the internet, and have the WRT between the Thomson and my LAN through its WAN port. However, the Thomson router is crappy and can't even do port forwards correctly.

My question is: (How) can I directly connect the WRT to the internet using the Thomson's modem? I want the WRT to get the external IP and all traffic, so the Thomson does as little work as possible, even just relaying packets, if I can. Otherwise, I can't forward any ports in any way, as the Thomson is broken.

Answer (score 0):

you almost there but is better to start from the beginning.

1° you need a modem to your network, so yes you really need the thomson, or other compatible device.

2° you need at least one firewall.

CONFIGURATION:

WRT firewall & wireless enabled

Thomson firewall & wireless disable

disable thomson firewall, stay only with WRT firewall, for security advice NEVER connect directly with thomson because you would not be protected by any firewall that include wireless network also so DISABLE wireless network on thomson.

you can also perform the changes by telnet commands, in some routers it is the only way. I can help you more if I know the model number.